# MS Access Multiple Report Parameter

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 subreports based on their respective union query (Previous month, current month, and next month) and all have the same 2 parameters (month and year).  When I place the 3 subreports onto an overall report, I have to type each parameter in 3 times.  Is there a way to make it so I'd only have to type month and year in once and that is able to pass-through to the other parameters? Preferably no visual basic as the others who will be working with this have little knowledge of coding...

Cheers mates and thanks in advance.

Comment: How are your parameters declared in your query right now?

Comment: I have them in the original queries (the ones the union queries pull from) set as just a standard parameter.

Comment: Can you post an example? Likely you can just reference a form control instead of a parameter. That's the easiest thing usually (though sometimes not the best) but let's see your query.

Comment: Which query should I post?  I have a staff form that allows for up to 5 project codes.  The codes are then pulled into 5 different queries (which have the parameters) and then they are unioned into a current month query which has its SQL Adjusted twice to create a next month and a previous month.

Comment: I just made some assumptions and posted an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a query like

```
Select * 
From SomeTable ST
Where ST.aColumn = YourParameter
```

Where `YourParameter` is what shows up in a popup dialog. Access asks for this because it is it is not the name of a column and can't resolve it to a control and you didn't provide a value (something you can do via VBA. A little more robust because it let's you specify parameters that are not bound to a particular form. Can also be called from outside Access)

You can reference a control instead though. So let's say the form which opens your report is called `ReportOpener` then you can have a textbox on your form called `txtParameter` (which you validate after your button click but before you open the report). Now your query can look like this

```
Select * 
From SomeTable ST
Where ST.aColumn = Forms!ReportOpener!txtParameter
```

This will only work if the form `ReportOpener` is open though, otherwise you'll get the same popup. Repeat this same logic for each parameter.

You can have a hidden text box which defaults to `=Date()` an duse that in your queries

```
Select * 
From SomeTable ST
Where ST.aDateColumn >= DateSerial(Year(Forms!ReportOpener!txtParameter), Month(Forms!ReportOpener!txtParameter) - 1, 1)
  and ST.aDateColumn < DateSerial(Year(Forms!ReportOpener!txtParameter), Month(Forms!ReportOpener!txtParameter) +2 1, 1)
```

So for example, today's date is `6/28/2016` which is the value of `Date()` which means

```
DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1) = 5/1/2016
```

and

```
DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 2, 1) = 8/1/2016
```

Do your date column would be bounded by

```
DateColumns >= 5/1/2016 and DateColumn < 8/1/2016
```

Which is last month, this month and next month.

Even though this parameter could be replaced entirely by `Date` it is still next to use the parameter because that way you can change what 3 month interval you are looking at.

Comment: Rather than an unknown column, I have a statement at the beginning:
PARAMETERS [Month] Text ( 255 ), [Year] Short;

Comment: @Dhill I'm not sure what you mean? A statement? At the beginning of what?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, at the beginning of the SQL, before the SELECT Statement:
PARAMETERS [Month (Abbreviate to 3 Letters)] Text ( 255 ), [Year (YYYY)] Short;
SELECT Staff.[Job Title]....

Comment: you mean that you have a `PARAMETERS` declaration statement? I think that's the only think allowed before "Select". If that's the case then you can ditch it. That's only really necessary (and even then not really) if you'll be providing the parameters via DAO or ADO.

Comment: Exactly, sorry! So should I now add in the WHERE?

Comment: You don't need the parameters section at all. Just reference your textbox directly instead. You can use the `Build... ` dialog on the query builder to find/properly reference your textbox if you want.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... could you elaborate please. Also, not intending on this being opened from a form.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where we lost eachother. Your query doesn't need to be anything more that my example in the answer. I can provide more specific detail if you update your question with more of your specifics though.

Comment: @Dhill if you're not intending for this to be opened from a form how will users open this? If no form then there is really no way around the popups.

Comment: It is a projection of the Manpower for the specific month you put in.  There is a current, next, and previous month using data from a Staff form (whether the person is still on the same project or if they left or not).  For that reason, there isn't really a place for it to be on a form - Just an open and see where the company will be in a few months

Comment: @Dhill If there is a form there is a way.  Sounds like you only need the 1 parameter. Just because a textbox is on a form doesn't mean it needs to be visible or require user input. I'll add to the answer for how to do that

Comment: @Dhill check out the update. Is that what you're expecting? Again, I could be more specific if you posted your query.

Comment: I see what is going on here but I do not think that it will be able to solve my problem.  The reason I am getting a popup 3 times is because I have 3 different subreports comprised from 3 different union queries.  The union queries are made from 5 seperate queries from each project option.  Each project option has a % that represents a persons FTE.  My goal is to Bring 3 sections to a report.  One for last month, this month, and next month.  Under each is the type of staff (3) and the sum of the FTE's for that staff type for that specific project.  Does this help? There are a total of 8 qrs

Comment: @Dhill And what happens when you change your queries to how my answer says? It seems like it is the solution still

Comment: When I change it to that it gives me an error message saying the field is not found.  In order for this to work, I'd need to have the form opened,  correct?

Comment: True, the form does need to be open. Did you use the builder to properly reference the control?

Comment: I did use the builder to reference.  Now I am getting a syntax error about a comma being in the query Expression.  I have a bit of different code than you because I have the month and year being converted to a date elsewhere
>>>  WHERE Staff.[Month (Abbreviate to 3 Letters)] = Forms!Form1!Month,Staff.[Year (YYYY)] = Forms!Forms1!Year;
This is in my Union query expression at the very end beneath all of the Union Statements

Comment: Probably best to leave that date as a date data type and let the Report do the formatting.

Comment: In the query, I am using a DateSerial function to combine them

Comment: OH... so what I did was instead of having a general where statement at the end of the SQL (which for some reason did not work), I changed every instance in the code of Month to Forms.Dates.Month and same with year.