# Access 2002 - How to: Parameter Query Wildcards

Tags: ms-access, parameters, report, reusability

I'm trying to do similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085018/ms-access-multiple-report-parameter).  I need a parameter to carry across multiple reports.  All the parameters in the query are the same, except they allow the user to use any part of a VIN (ie last 5, last 6, last 7...etc.) so I am using wildcards as:

```
Like "*" & [Enter partial VIN] & "*"
```

This allows users to enter 12345 and the query would return a 17 character VIN containing 12345 with any suffix of prefix.  My questions is how to I implement the above using the wildcards.  I tried quoting the wildcards, double-quoting the wildcards and the query is still mad.

The overall goal is to complete a deal, then I want to create a single Quick Print button that will print all reports related to a sale (7 reports) that all use the same parameter.  Currently, I have to open each, enter the same parameter and then print.  The macro I can do (and did), except it currently prompts me each time for the parameter.

Update:  I'm so confused...should I be calling the original reports field name for the rest of the reports and basically state in each additional report

```
parameter = First_Report.ParameterName
```

?

Bonus:
I would think there would be a way to pass the parameter (silently) and just print all required reports.  When I am using the macro there are screen flashes of the report opening, queuing, printing, closing, then repeats to the next.  Can't this be performed without actually displaying the reports or just a message displaying "Printing reports, please wait...".

I hope asking this question in this thread was acceptable as it's an 'addition to' question to the original.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about the obvious: "SQL database have but one data structure, therefore put the value to search on in a table, then join your reports' source queries to this table" ...?

Comment: Perhaps obvious to you.  Of the seven reports, 5 use unique queries.  Other reports use other queries by this table but not all search by VIN.  Some queries use customer.ID tied to vehicle.ID when its sold, then there is service.id to vehicle.ID, but VIN is common on all (used) queries.

Right now all individual reports I want to use have the same parameter for the (VIN), but the same query, I just need to "link" them so entering the parm one carries to the next, and so on.

Comment: *the query is still mad*...please be more specific. Why doesn't your `LIKE` statement work? It should correctly search *12345* anywhere in the VIN field. Also, to synch all reports to same parameter just use a form with textbox for partial VIN and have all reports look to this textbox.

Comment: Individually, the reports work great, including the parameter with the wildcards.  I was (am) working on how to pass it to all reports and will try what you suggest, thank you.  This is where the query was mad, but due to frankensteining a solution.

Comment: Why don't you use a form control for the user to enter the parameter once, then use the criteria: `Like "*" & [Forms]![MyForm]![MyParameterControl] & "*"` in each of your queries? That's assuming the data type of your VIN field is text.

Comment: Q. I have a single value I want to use in multiple views in my database. How to do this? A. Put the value in a table and point your queries at it e.g.  `DELETE FROM MyParamTable;` `INSERT INTO MyParamTable ( ParamValueColumn ) VALUES ( <value goes here> );` then in queries `... AND VIN Like "*" & MyParamTable.ParamValueColumn & "*" AND ...`